# Are they twin primes?

Tags: number-theory, twin-primes

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $p_1, p_2,...,p_n$ be first n primes. And let $m$ be the smallest integer $m\ge\,p_n$ such that $m$ and $m+2$ are coprime to $p_1,p_2,..., p_n$.

Are $m$ and $m+2$ always prime?

Comment: This statement would immediately imply the twin prime conjecture, so it's certainly not *known* to be true.  (Perhaps it's known to be *false*, though -- I don't know.)

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I think ElliotG's answer is complete with Betrand's Postulate.

Comment: @roby5: You think the twin prime conjecture can be proven in three lines with 150-year-old machinery?

Comment: To be coprime to $p_1,p_2,..., p_n$ and still composite, $m$ or $m+2$ should be a product of some bigger primes, which would imply the absence of twin prime pairs between $p_n$ and $p_n^2$, which (informally) is unlikely and gets even less likely as $n$ grows. But of course we don't know for sure, because twin prime conjecture and stuff.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Give me sometime to prove this using Betrand's Postulate. In the meantime, you try proving that this is not possible using Betrand's Postulate.

Comment: No counterexample found up to $n=100\,000$.

Comment: I've searched up to $n=1000000$ without finding a counterexample.